# Why won't this global variable work? It works perfectly as a local variable

Tags: javascript, scope, global-variables

I want to make the "myColor" variable global so that I don't have to paste it into every function but I can't get it to work. How can I get it to work? Any help is much appreciated.

```
var myColor = document.getElementById("colorSelect").value; //this global variable isn't working

function r1c1BackgroundColor() { // Isn't working 
    document.getElementsByClassName("tableBox")[0].style.backgroundColor = myColor;
}

function r1c2BackgroundColor() { // works fine
    var myColor = document.getElementById("colorSelect").value;
    document.getElementsByClassName("tableBox")[1].style.backgroundColor = myColor;
}
```

```html
<tr>
<td id="r1c1" class="tableBox" onclick="r1c1BackgroundColor()"></td>
<td id="r1c2" class="tableBox" onclick="r1c2BackgroundColor()"></td>
<td id="r1c3" class="tableBox" onclick="r1c3BackgroundColor()"></td>

<!-- etc -->
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a element containing the value of `myColor`, also you have not defined `r1c3BackgroundColor`, in the code! The global variable seems to work fine, as long as there is an element to get its value from!

```js
function r1c1BackgroundColor() { // Isn't working 
    myColor = document.getElementById("colorSelect").value;
    document.getElementsByClassName("tableBox")[0].style.backgroundColor = myColor;
}

function r1c2BackgroundColor() { // works fine
    myColor = document.getElementById("colorSelect").value;
    document.getElementsByClassName("tableBox")[1].style.backgroundColor = myColor;
}
function r1c3BackgroundColor() { // works fine
    myColor = document.getElementById("colorSelect").value;
    document.getElementsByClassName("tableBox")[2].style.backgroundColor = myColor;
}
```

```html
<input id="colorSelect" value="#000000"/>
<table>
<tr>
<td id="r1c1" class="tableBox" onclick="r1c1BackgroundColor()">first</td>
<td id="r1c2" class="tableBox" onclick="r1c2BackgroundColor()">second</td>
<td id="r1c3" class="tableBox" onclick="r1c3BackgroundColor()">third</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Clicking on `first` always makes it black, no matter what you put in the input.

Answer (score 0):

Your global variable is being set when the document is first loaded, and never updated when the user fills in the input.

If you don't want to write that code every time, make it a function:

```
function getMyColor() {
    return document.getElementById("colorSelect").value;
}
```

Then you can call it in all the places that need it:

```
function r1c1BackgroundColor() { // Isn't working 
    document.getElementsByClassName("tableBox")[0].style.backgroundColor = getMyColor();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I thought it would be something with "return" but I was using it in the wrong way. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your global variable is getting executed before the element with id **colorSelect** is attached to DOM i.e. document.

So, what happens is when your global variable right side of the expression i.e. **document.getElementById("colorSelect").value;** executes, its value comes as undefined and hence global variable **myColor** value becomes equal to undefined. So where ever you are using global variable, its value is undefined.

Its working in case of local variable because the function i.e. **r1c2BackgroundColor** is invoked on click of

```
<td id="r1c2" class="tableBox" onclick="r1c2BackgroundColor()"></td>
```

and by this time, element with id **colorSelect** is attached to DOM and hence the local variable value is not coming as undefined and it works fine.

To solve this problem you can use document readystatechange event and readyState  property.

Wrapping up, you can do something like this.

```
var myColor;

document.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (document.readyState === "interactive") {
    myColor = document.getElementById("colorSelect").value;
  }
}

function r1c1BackgroundColor() { 
    document.getElementsByClassName("tableBox")[0].style.backgroundColor = myColor;
}

function r1c2BackgroundColor() { 
    document.getElementsByClassName("tableBox")[1].style.backgroundColor = myColor;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This still won't work if he updates the input, it will use its original value from when the document was loaded.

Comment: true but i am assuming that a default value will be set to the input on page load.

Comment: The normal purpose of an input is to allow the user to change the value.